# What's wrong with this toggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

## [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EhzwV/)

I have the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div></div>
        Testing
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li>
                <div></div>
                Testing
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm calling this js on it:

```
$('li').hide(2000);
```

Now I have a border around the div's What I want is for the borders to fade too, but as you can see the borders are first disappearing completely and then the rest of the elements slowly fade.

Is there anything I can do so that the borders fade like the rest of the element?

Comment: What browser are you using? The borders fade just fine for me in chrome 12, ie8 and FF4

Comment: It works if you do not reposition the div http://jsfiddle.net/EhzwV/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works if you try to hide the 'ul' instead, and has the same effect on the DOM visibility.

```
setTimeout( function() { $('ul').hide(2000); }, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EhzwV/1/

Answer (score 1):

The hide animation sets `overflow: hidden` on your elements, that is what is causing this.  You can see this if you set the overflow yourself with no animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/EhzwV/2/

Comment: Is there any way I can force it not to change to hidden?

Comment: Well you could do `overflow:visible !important;` on the `li`.  But this will ruin the effect of hide.  If you are going to do this, you're better off just using `fadeOut`.  The way that the element shrinks as it disappears requires this hidden overflow.

Comment: Alternatively, you could redesign a bit to eliminate the elements overhanging the left side of the `li`.  Then they wont' get cut off.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide all the li elements. If you want any specific element to hide pass the appropriate selector

```
$('ul').hide(2000);//This will work for you I guess
```